# How to find a bug in my Pong game?

Tags: javascript

I am working on a game, Pong, and I am trying to get the ball to bounce off the paddle but it is not working. Instead it is doing the "resetGame" thing instead. I put in `console.log` things to see when it's not working and figured out that it's not doing the `if` statement and it's going straight to the `else` statement even though I am doing the things that should trigger the `if` statement.

By the way, I'm using JavaScript, and it doesn't say there are any errors in the console ***and*** I am just opening it with Google.

Here's code:

```
<html>
    <h3>- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -PONG- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -</h3>

    <canvas id="gameCanvas" width="800" height="600"></canvas>

    <script>
        var canvas;
        var canvasContext;
        var ballX = 50;
        var ballY = 50;
        var ballSpeedX = 11;
        var ballSpeedY = 5;

        var playerPaddleY = 240;
        const paddleHeight = 120;

        function calculateMousePos(evt) {
            var rect = canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
            var root = document.documentElement;
            var mouseX = evt.clientX - rect.left - root.scrollLeft;
            var mouseY = evt.clientY - rect.top - root.scrollTop;
            return {
                x:mouseX,
                y:mouseY
            };
        }

        window.onload = function() {
            canvas = document.getElementById('gameCanvas');
            canvasContext = canvas.getContext('2d');

            var framesPerSecond = 30;

            setInterval(function() {
                moveEverything();
                drawEverything();
            }, 1000/framesPerSecond );

            canvas.addEventListener('mousemove',
                function(evt) {
                    var mousePos = calculateMousePos(evt);
                    playerPaddleY = mousePos.y- (paddleHeight/2);
                });
        }

        function ballReset() {
            ballX = canvas.width/2;
            ballY = canvas.height/2;
            ballSpeedX = -ballSpeedX;
        }

        function moveEverything() {
            ballX = ballX + ballSpeedX;
            ballY = ballY + ballSpeedY;

            if (ballX > canvas.width) {
                ballReset();
            }

            if(ballX < 0) {
                console.log("hello");
                if(ballY > playerPaddleY && ballY < paddleHeight) {
                    console.log("hellooo");
                    ballSpeedX = -ballSpeedX;
                }
                else {
                    console.log("helloooooo");
                    ballReset();
                }
            }

            if(ballY > canvas.height) {
                ballSpeedY = -ballSpeedY;
            }

            if(ballY < 0) {
                ballSpeedY = -ballSpeedY;
            }
        }

        function drawEverything() {
            canvasContext.fillStyle = 'black';
            canvasContext.fillRect(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);
            canvasContext.fillStyle = 'white';
            canvasContext.fillRect(0, playerPaddleY, 13, paddleHeight); // player

            canvasContext.fillRect(785, 240, 13, 120); //computer player

            canvasContext.beginPath();
            canvasContext.arc(ballX, ballY, 10, 0,Math.PI*2, true); //ball
            canvasContext.fill();
        }
    </script>
</html>
```

Comment: Trademark capitalization; spelling; grammar; noise reduction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the line.

```
if(ballY > playerPaddleY && ballY < paddleHeight) {
```

which you want to change to

```
if((ballY > playerPaddleY) && (ballY < (playerPaddleY + paddleHeight))) {
```

If you console.log() ballY, playerPaddleY and paddleHeight it will become evident that you are currently comparing the ballY position to the height in pixels of the paddle, which obviously fails.